# Resizing div is slow in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 1440*900 monitor; a page with header, footer, and two DIVs between them (the first is my main-content DIV and the second is under it, with the same width)

I need to resize the second DIV (it uses the same background as the main-content DIV does) to feel the gap between footer and bottom of window (if there is some)

I use this code :

```
while($("#page").height() < wh){
    $("#spacer").css('height', (parseInt($("#spacer").css('height').replace('px', '')) + 1) + 'px');
}
```

I use it in document-ready (jquery), but it freezes in Chrome (but not in firefox).

Comment: It freezes because it is stuck in one of those while loops, try debugging it and see what happens.

Comment: I feel a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of kittens cried out in terror

Comment: If you find yourself copy-and-pasting code, you're doing it wrong. If you find yourself copy-and-pasting code *seven times* you're definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: `$("#spacer")` is repeated 14 times…

Comment: @Tomalak :| :| :| so answer now ! :|

Comment: :| :| :| looks like everybody has problem with copy paste ! :|

Comment: @EbrahimTahernejad your performance problem is not with JavaScript, but with DOM updates. Compute the height you want and set it, or better yet make the layout work with CSS rules instead of JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy : I killed myself with css ! :| and calculating wont work, it's always a 10-20px distance left (and is different in to some browsers and even some versions of one browser)

Comment: Here's my tip: You are definitely not the first person in the world who wants to create a sticky footer. Search the internet, read and learn what other people did.

Comment: As _Tomalak_ says you are not the first one trying to solve sticky footer. But if you really want to try or need to do this yourself, you should probably think about something like `outerWidthSecondDiv = totalHeight - outerHeightHeader - outerHeightFooter - outerHeightMainContent` Using a while loop here is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making classes in your CSS file for your different sizes, and then just using jQuery to change the class. Might be faster.

.addClass

or

.attr('heightClass', 'whateverClassYouWant')

Answer (score 0):

What's that? That code is repeated. And I wouldn't use while. I would use an event detector,

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    if ($(window).height>value) {
        //do stuff
    }
    else if ($(window).height<value) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
);

$(document).ready ( function(e) { //the same } );
```

While makes it slower. try not to use while in that ocasions, while hasn't been created for that, there are event listeners, while stays there till the condition changes or you break it.

Comment: *"try not to use while in javascript"* - that's complete nonsense. (Hint: It's not the language construct that causes the problem here, it's the way it is used. Avoiding `while` buys you nothing, JS has plenty of other language constructs to use wrongly. You're not helping the OP with a tip like *"avoid `while`"*. Apart from that, making it seem like `while` is something "advanced" is not useful either.)

Comment: @EbrahimTahernejad try doing that. If you tell me what you exactly wanna do, I can help you build the code. Copy-and-paste doesn't make sense with the same condition, and the code was not reasoned. You have to think what will JS do when it reads it, to help you understand how the code works and how might you do it for it to work --and go as-fast-as-- you want.

Comment: You mean how I say it or the meaning itself? I said so because it will stuck in that code, I meant in that case, @Tomalak .

Comment: Using while in JavaScript is fine as long as you make sure there is ***NO*** way that it will become an infinite loop. (can't account for someone editing the JS)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I was talking about that piece of code, which stucks there, because the problem is that JS doesn't show the DOM content till the while stops, as I have experienced, correct me if I'm wrong. But in that case, with the windows, it won't do want you want, you have to use event, which is made exactly for that type of stuff. The while hasn't been designed for that code usage, @Lugia101101 ,